# Shell script error to extract file data

Tags: shell, error-handling

I have attempted to write a shell script and it is giving an error which I cannot understand. The script goes like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read id 
do 
cat demuxR1/$id.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq demuxR2/$id.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq > alldemulti/$id.forwardread.fastq 
done < R1_new.txt
```

the files in demuxR1 and demuxR2 folder contain files [image] named as shown. The output has to be redirected into another folder called alldemulti. When I am running the script it complains

```
cat: demuxR1/SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq: No such file or directory
```

The `R1_new.txt` conatins the file names :

```
    SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
    SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
    SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Content of `demuxR1` directory:

```
total 4426752
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy        561 Oct 15 08:46 barcode_R1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     231092 Oct 15 09:14 SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     235734 Oct 15 09:14 SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     917692 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     935522 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1129320 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1151554 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     747736 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     762462 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     446168 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     455044 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     378862 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     386440 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     960420 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     979364 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1256116 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1281112 Oct 15 09:14 SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy 2258319418 Oct 15 09:14 unknown.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy 2257956950 Oct 15 09:14 unknown.R2.fastq
```

Content of `demuxR2` directory:

```
total 4427776
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy        560 Oct 14 12:48 barcode_R2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     261854 Oct 15 10:11 SAE1903.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     256718 Oct 15 10:11 SAE1903.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1284362 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2000.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1259358 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2000.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1208280 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2103.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1184716 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2103.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1028542 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2203.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1008462 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2203.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     627558 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2303.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     615364 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2303.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     414098 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2403.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy     405878 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2403.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1231900 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2603.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1208060 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2603.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1784282 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2803.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy    1749406 Oct 15 10:11 SAE2803.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy 2256301114 Oct 15 10:11 unknown.R1.fastq
-rwxrwxrwx 1 moloy moloy 2256668336 Oct 15 10:11 unknown.R2.fastq
```

Comment: What's in `R1_new.txt`?

Comment: it contain the file names

Comment: it contains these names : SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2103.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2203.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2303.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2403.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2603.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE2803.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq

Comment: Add updated information to the question itself, not in comments (where formatting gets lost). It looks like you're reading filenames, but your code expects only the `SAE2000` bit in front of the first dot. Add the formatted input file in the question (or part of it) and all will be clearer.

Comment: should I start a new thread I dont see any options for editing my original question

Comment: This is confusing. Your two directories contain files with the same name. How do you know what directory you should pick the files from to concatenate, or are you always taking the first file (the `R1` file) from `demuxR1` and the second from `demuxR2`?

Comment: I was doing it wrongly. Corrected the script. #!/bin/bash
while read id 
do 
cat demuxR1/$id.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq demuxR2/$id.barcode.in.R2.R2.fastq > alldemulti/$id.forwardread.fastq 
done < R1.txt and #!/bin/bash
while read id
do
cat demuxR1/$id.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq demuxR2/$id.barcode.in.R2.R1.fastq > alldemulti/$id.reverseread.fastq
done < R1.txt........and now it works. Thank you so much for your efforts. Sorry to have taken so much of your time and thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your input file actually only contains one file name per line and looks like this:

```
SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq
SAE2000.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq
...
```

Your script reads each line into `id`, so after the first line the value of `id` is `SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq`. If you now use this as `$id.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq` the variable is replaced by the value, and then the rest of the string (`.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq`) gets appended. Which then, of course, leads to the error because there is no file called `SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq.barcode.in.R1.R1.fastq`.

A simple solution (which assumes a file with an even number of lines) to overcome this could be

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line1; do
    read line2
    cat "demuxR1/$line1" "demuxR2/$line2" > "alldemulti/${line1%%.*}.forwardread.fastq"
done < R1_new.txt
```

The `${line1%%.*}` will be replaced by e.g. `SAE1903`, i.e. the word before the first dot in the string read from the file.

Comment: @Kusalnanda I tried the script with the suggested changes but curiously it complains "cat: demuxR2/SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq: No such file or directory". There are no files by such a name in demuxR2. The script that I ran was #!/bin/bash
while read line1; do
    read line2
    cat "demuxR1/$line1" "demuxR2/$line2" > "alldemulti/SAE1903.forwardread.fastq"
done < R1_new.txt. Myquestion is that for the next round of processing I need the output of all the ID's together in one file. How can I achieve this using this script ?

Comment: @user1738234 The script just is a copy of the one you've included in the question. In which directory is `SAE1903.barcode.in.R1.R2.fastq` (or more generally all the `...R2.fastq`) file stored, and is the name correct?

Comment: @user1738234 According to the screenshot in the question all input files seem to be in `demuxR1`. If this is the case replace `demuxR2` with `demuxR1` in the code snippet. If not, please update your question to show more clearly which files are in `demuxR1` and which in `demuxR2` (maybe just copy/paste the result of `ls -l demuxR1 demuxR2`)